# SPFolder.Exists Returns False When It Does Exist

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

I have the following code in a web service that connects to Sharepoint:

```
string response = string.Empty;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(new SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite spsite = new SPSite("http://sharepoint/"))
    {
        using (SPWeb spweb = spsite.OpenWeb("sites/" + site))
        {
            spweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            SPFolder spfolder = spweb.GetFolder(path);

            /* The following value will always be set to FALSE
             * but the next time spfolder.Exists is called, the
             * returned value will be true.
             */
            //bool exists = spfolder.Exists;

            if (spfolder == null || !spfolder.Exists)
                response = "Folder Does Not Exist!";
            else
                response = "Folder Exists!";
        }
    }
}

return response;
```

The code as it is above works perfectly fine if I debug it step-by-step starting at the top. If I run it without debugging or if I put a breakpoint somewhere later on in the code, the SPFolder.Exists value is always set to false, when, in fact, it should be true.  If I uncomment out the `bool exists` line above, then it will work fine.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Potential answer: ask for some more interesting property of `SPFolder` first, maybe even call `ToString` would be enough (likely since it works in debugger where `ToString` will be called when you hover over `spFolder` variable).

Comment: Well, yes, it's just SharePoint. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured out what the problem was.  Apparently, you can only specify site collections in an SPSite object and sites/subsites for SPWeb.  What I was trying to do was open a web that was a root web for another site collection.

This [article](http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/openwebstring-method/) helped me figure that out.

Changing the code to something like this fixes the problem:

```
// Specify ONLY the site collection here
using (SPSite spsitecollection = new SPSite("http://sharepoint/sites/" + srcSiteCollection))
{
    // Specify the site/subsite
    using (SPWeb spweb = spsitecollection.OpenWeb(srcSite))
    {

        spweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        SPFolder spfolder = spweb.GetFolder(path);

        // No errors anymore!
        if (spfolder == null || !spfolder.Exists)
            response = "Folder Does Not Exist!";
        else
            response = "Folder Exists!";
    }
}
```